# what's wrong with the rawQuery?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i really have no idea why my query give an error every thing looks good but logcat shows msg syntax error.please check guys whats worng in my query.

```
public class ContactDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="totalContact1.db";
    public static final  String TABLE_NAME="mecontact1";
    public static final  String NAME="name";
    public static final  String PHONE="phone";
    public static final  String UID="_id";


    public ContactDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("create table mecontact1" +
                    "(_id integer primary key , name text, phone text)");
        }catch(android.database.SQLException e){
                System.out.println("table create nhi ho rha");
        }
    }
 public Cursor forEditPurpose(int pos){

        db=this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT, " + UID + ", name, phone FROM mecontact1 where " + UID + " = " + pos + "", null);
   return res;

    }
}
```

logcat status is:

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT, _id, name, phone FROM mecontact1 where _id = 1
```

Comment: `"SELECT, "` this is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this line delete the first "," after SELECT

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT, " + UID + ", name, phone FROM mecontact1 where " + UID + " = " + pos + "", null);
```

It would be

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT " + UID + ", name, phone FROM mecontact1 where " + UID + " = " + pos + "", null);
```

Comment: you are welcome, though a proper thanks wold be  accepting  the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT, "
    + UID + ", name, phone FROM mecontact1 where "
    + UID + " = " + pos + "", null);
```

To:

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT "
    + UID + ", name, phone FROM mecontact1 where "
    + UID + " = " + pos + "", null);
```